# date and datetime issues in a complicated context

Tags: mysql

After i imported a large csv into a table i ran into a major problem in my case:
the format of the date in the csv it's DD MM YYYY, and when i try importing that into a date/datetime it won't work. So ok I did it with a CHAR type instead of DATE/DATETIME and it works so far. (my example: VisitTime CHAR(10) )

> **BUT here is the problem**, with the data inside the CHAR I can't concatenate to make a datetime column from 2 columns ( my example is: VisitTime CHAR(10) which was supposed to be DATE but isn't working since it's wrong format DD MM YYYY and HourTime which is TIME.
>       **Bottom line:** i need a column in another table VisitTimeandHour DATETIME which results from a concatenation of VisitTIME CHAR(10) and a HourTime TIME.
>       A solution was maybe making all the columns that i talked about VARCHAR and it was i think no problem, but i wanna stick with date and datetime :) 
>       Waiting for solutions, thanks in advance.

Correct me if i'm wrong  but if i try to import into a variable then converting it would be ok?, and by the way an example of date that needs to be converted from the csv is: 22/04/2005 ) the code:

> SET @var1 = NULL;
>   load data infile 'xxxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx'
>       into table vizite_intermtest
>       character set utf8
>       fields terminated by ','
>       lines terminated by '\n'
>       ignore 1 lines
>       (@var1,OraIntrare,NumePacient,PrenumePacient,NumeMedic,PrenumeMedic,Cabinet)
>       SET VisitTime = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%d/%m/%y');

If i try this it says: truncated inccorect value 22/04/2005 (the VisitTime column that i wanna import in it's a CHAR type)

> LE: It works to import into a variable and to convert it but altough i put the  / / / between them it still gives me the time format with - - - ... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stick with the DATE / DATETIME fields, but tell MySQL how to interpret the incoming data.  I'm not certain how you imported the data, but the function to interpret a string as a date is `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
STR_TO_DATE( '01 02 2003', '%d %m %Y' )
```

For more info, see the following:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: maybe if i set a variable and import from the csv in that and afterwards maybe setting it and converting it to a proper date type of date might work?

Comment: Your post kind of helped me scooping for something else, finally it worked out by the method i posted up there. But it doesn't imports to my exactly format with / / / , it's with  - - - giving the definition above maybe helping with that if u can?

Comment: A bit of a guess but I think you have put %y instead of %Y - it is case sensitive because %y is a two-digit year, while %Y is for four-digit.